# How to inner join two tables to junction table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I'm kinda stuck here joining two tables into junction table. I have 3 tables **roles** and **permissions** that linked to **roles_permissions_dt** which is my junction table.

**roles**

```
id - PK

role_type - VARCHAR
```

**permissions**

```
id - PK

permission_type - VARCHAR
```

**roles_permissions_dt**

```
id - PK
role_id - FK REFERENCES(roles)
permission_id - FK REFERENCES(permissions)
```

These are the values that I created in my **roles** and **permissions** tables.

**roles Screenshot**

[image: roles]

**permissions Screenshot**

[image: permissions]

I want to join **roles** table with an `id` of `1` and **permissions** table with an `id` of `1` to my `roles_permissions_table`. How can I achieve this using inner join?

This is my attempt query. But still don't have any idea to join this in my junction table.

```
SELECT roles.id, permissions.id FROM roles INNER JOIN permissions;
```

Comment: Hello fellowmate, @1000111's answer should work fine. Can you show us the rows of `roles_permissions_dt ` table?

Comment: Give us sample source data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM roles_permissions_dt RP
INNER JOIN roles R ON RP.role_id = R.id 
INNER JOIN permissions P ON RP.permission_id = P.id;
```

Also you can filter data using `WHERE` clause like below:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM roles_permissions_dt RP
INNER JOIN roles R ON RP.role_id = R.id 
INNER JOIN permissions P ON RP.permission_id = P.id
WHERE RP.role_id = ? AND RP.permission_id = ?;
```

Comment: I tried your second option and I passed a values in the `WHERE` clause but didn't show me the values in the junction table.

Comment: what kind of data you have in your junction table, and which exact query(including conditional parameter values) you fire to get records?

Comment: Better share the `schema` of those three tables including some sample data in an **SQL FIDDLE**. @Francisunoxx